# R count how many times a value appears in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame. All columns are numbers.
How to count the times that a value appears in all the data frame?
For example the number 9999.

Comment: Try: `sum(df[df==9999])`

Answer (score 2):

In R (and many programming languages) counting is done as a sum of a logical condition - `TRUE` is equivalent to `1`, and `FALSE` is equivalent to `0`. In this case, if your data is named `df` then `df == 9999` gives `TRUE` when the data is 9999 and `FALSE` otherwise, and to count the number of `TRUE` values we use `sum()`:

```
sum(df == 9999)
```